# Can I somehow store a block for later usage?

Tags: ruby

Ok here is what I want to do:

I pass a block to a method like: `Generator.generate(...) {|x| ...}`. I want to store the block because I call it in some sub routine that gets called a bunch of times from different places.

Sure I could drag along &block through all methods and calls, but I want to actually save it in a class variable and use it in the appropriate method.

Something like this:

```
class Generator
  class << self
    attr_accessor :my_block

    def generate(..., &block)
      my_block = &block
      ....each {important_method(x)}
    end

    def important_method(x)
      my_block.yield(x)
    end
  end
end
```

Is it possible to store a block and yield it later with some arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make 2 adjustments to your code:

```
class Generator
  class << self
    attr_accessor :my_block

    def generate(..., &block)
      self.my_block = block # Because otherwise you're just setting a method-local variable
      ....each {important_method(x)}
    end

    def important_method(x)
      my_block.call(x) # Because this is how Proc objects are called
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If your method accepts block in `&block` form, then it's converted to a Proc object and can be stored to variable. You can call it later by sending it a `call` message.

```
my_block.call(x)
```

Another example

```
class Foo

  def init &block
    @my_block = block
  end

  def process ary
    ary.each do |a|
      @my_block.call a
    end
    #   or this
    # ary.each(&@my_block)
  end
end

f = Foo.new
f.init {|a| puts a}
f.process [1, 2, 3]
```